# Trigger suspension events in a Windows Store app App 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

How to trigger suspension of events in a Windows Store app App 8.1 after being idle for a certain period of time? Or simply how to suspend it after being idle for a certain period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force suspend the app, you can terminate it, it'll be suspended automatically after a period of time.. but you can trigger that by subscribing to OnSusbended Event in app.xaml.cs:

```
this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
```

Handler:

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //Use deferral for await calls :)       

            deferral.Complete();
        }
```

Btw, you can debug it using VS, refer to this: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974425.aspx

**UPDATE:**

Because the app is `Suspended`, you can't run a code to check, but what you can do is: Save a value to the settings in your app once the app is suspended, let's say it's: `IsSuspended = 1`, and make it `0` whenever the app rises OnActivated Event, this is a good way to check from a BackgroundTask or your foreground app after resuming.

Comment: I know this. you answer just a part of the question. but how detect that application is idle ?

Comment: The app registers event handlers and prepares the UI before it enters the Running state and occupies the full screen. The user can send the app to the background by swapping with another app that is already running. The first app enters the Suspended state when it is sent to the background by the user. The app can remain in the Suspended state until the user brings it in the foreground by swapping with an app in the foreground, or it may be terminated by Windows if the operating system determines the app is consuming a lot of resources while in the background.

Comment: Windows allows 10 seconds for your application to suspend, so you must ensure that saving data and state information in the Suspending event handler does not take longer than 10 seconds. If the app takes longer than 10 seconds in the event handler, Windows assumes your app is not responding and terminates it.